# High session memory usage in Mojarra

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, websphere-7, mojarra

I have a web application build on Mojarra (JSF 2). The application is deployed on WebSphere 7. The session usage for my application is very high. I use view scoped beans and some of the pages are considerably large. My web xml is configured to keep 5 views in session.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
  <param-value>5</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
  <param-value>5</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I am not explicitly adding anything to session. Still some of the sessions in my application is as large as 60 MB.

When I do a hepdump analysis it shows the session hashmap is taking all the memory. Is there a way to identify what exactly is there in session store?

E.g. The retained heap com.ibm.ws.session.store.memory.MemorySession @ 0x700000057890108  for memory store xxx at /xxx/yyy is 66209288.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you analyze your heap dump with [eclipse-memory-analyzer](/questions/tagged/eclipse-memory-analyzer), you should be able to drill down your `com.ibm.ws.session.store.memory.MemorySession` to find the culprit, as explained in this blog entry: [Richfaces Sessions Eating Memory – Analysis of a Memory Leak](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/08/richfaces-sessions-eating-memory-analysis-of-a-memory-leak/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In my case it is an array of javax.faces.component.UIOutput objects.